# one2many field view - attribute

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13, xml-attribute

I have the following wizard structure [ field name and data type ]

- Type :- Selection :- Type 1 and Type 2
- Route :- One2many

When Users select Type 1, I want to allow them to add records in the Route table. While on the Type 2, I want to make Route readonly and don't allow deletion. I will fill it with default route information.

I write following code in the .xml file:

```
<group attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '=', 'type_2')]}">
    <field name="route_ids" string="Testing 1">
        <tree>
            <field name="x"/>
            <field name="y"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</group>

<group attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '=', 'type_1')]}">
    <field name="route_ids" string="Testing 2">
        <tree delete="false" create="false">
            <field name="x"/>
            <field name="y"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</group>
```

I notice that based on Type selection, route field label is changing but tree attributes (readonly, delete) remain same / whatever set in the last.

Expectation:

One2many field attribute should be refreshed instead of keeping last.

I resolved it by adding a new field and onchange method but I'm looking for a better approach to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the problem, I have two solution:

1. Adding a new One2many, fill data via onchange method

   ```
   printing_route_ids = fields.One2many(
       string='Printing Route',
       comodel_name='x.y.z.wizard',
       inverse_name='printing_x_y_z_id',     # printing_x_y_z_id is a M2O in a line level table
   )
   ```

   I have another O2M field called "QC Route" which is editable. So transfer all QC routes to the Printing route and from Printing Route, I updated the final Route field so I do need to write custom logic to manage different routes. In my case, I have multiple types so route_ids field is very important.

   ```
   @api.onchange('qc_route_ids')
   def onchange_qc_route_ids(self):
    if self.type == "type_1":
        self.printing_route_ids = False
        mrp_workcenter_lines = []
        # My other logic

        # Prepare qc route
        for line in self.qc_route_ids:
            qc_vals = {
                'operation': line.operation,
                'workcenter_id': line.workcenter_id.id,
                'sequence': line.sequence,
                'note': line.note,
                'worksheet': line.worksheet,
            }
            mrp_workcenter_lines.append((0, 0, qc_vals))
        self.printing_route_ids = mrp_workcenter_lines
   ```

   On the done button click, I transfer all values to the final Route.

   ```
   def button_done(self):
       if self.type == "type_1":
           self.route_ids = self.printing_route_ids
       # leave all logic same with changing route_ids
       return True
   ```

   And xml side, for the second group, I replaced field from "route_ids" to "printing_route_ids"
2. @Kenly's answer. Add dependency of module [web_action_conditionable](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/13.0/web_action_conditionable) and apply condition to one2many tree view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [web_action_conditionable](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/13.0/web_action_conditionable) module, it adds support for conditions on `create` and `delete` actions on One2Many fields.

***Example:***

```
<field name="route_ids">
    <tree delete="type=='type_2'" create="type=='type_2'">
        <field name="x"/>
        <field name="y"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: Thank you Kenly. It makes sense. I will go with my own solution because I don't want to add extra module dependency in my project. [ I haven't found any Odoo core attributes solution to achieve it. ]

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to make your delete-attribute dynamic:

```xml
    <tree t-att-delete="'false' if type=='type_1' else 'true'" >
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will not work.  Review my code in the question, before one2many field, I have a group and it is toggle based on type. For a type 1, I want to display it at 2nd block while for type 2, at the end all fields.

Comment: So I have to go with 2 times field declaration and apply different attributes.

Comment: yup, I tried it different ways and didn't work. - keep display one field and apply code,    - keep display two field and apply code.

Comment: How about adding an empty <tree /> before your second tree to differenciate tree[2] from tree[1] ?

Comment: I added empty tree tag as per your suggestion and didn't work.

Comment: How about using js or jquery ressource with an $(".type_class").onchange() that will add the DELETE button inside each tr-nodes : $('tr').append('<td class="o_list_record_remove"><button class="fa fa-trash-o" name="delete" aria-label="DELETE THIS RECORD"></button></td>')

Comment: I am not good in js so IMO adding a new field is simple enough. I am trying to find Odoo core attributes without making more complex. I reported issue to Odoo because this is straight forward requirement. Thanks for your help on it.